# Automatic height for TextView using autolayout in cell for tableView

Tags: swift, autolayout, storyboard, tableview

I want to set the height of the TextView as per content in a cell for tableview.

[image]

i pinned the top of text view to the job title UILabel and bottom to the content view (parent) but it does not working. is there any tutorial for this kind of layout positioning ?

How i add constraint to fix the automatic height issue?

Current constraints
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved this way.**
Change the TextView to UILabel, Then set **Lines** property in the attribute inspector to 0.

on viewDidLoad

```swift
    tableview.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
    tableview.estimatedRowHeight = 229.0
```

It works.

More https://www.raywenderlich.com/8549-self-sizing-table-view-cells

Comment: glad you solved it. but there are some functionalities that textView has but the label does not.

Answer (score 1):

As I can see you have some other setup as well in the cell. to support dynamic height

1. you can give fix height constraint to UITextView.
2. take outlet of that constraint.
3. update it before you return the cell from `cellForRowAt` method.

so, your cellForRowAt method will end up like

```
tableCell.textViewHeightConstraint = textView.contentSize.height
tableCell.setNeedsUpdateConstraints()
tableCell.setNeedsLayout()
return tableCell
```

Answer (score -1):

You can apply Self-Sizing Table View Cells by adding two lines:

```
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 85.0
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

You should read this document from Apple:
https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/WorkingwithSelf-SizingTableViewCells.html

Comment: Is it because of the cell height not expanding or because the constraints of the TextView is wrong?

Comment: tableview.estimatedRowHeight = 85.0 
tableview.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension   not works

Comment: Are you still using cellForRowAtIndexPath?

Comment: How about tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:?
Are you using it?

Comment: solved issue by changing the textview to uiLabel and setting Lines property to zero. then the automatic dimension works, thanks guys

Comment: https://www.raywenderlich.com/8549-self-sizing-table-view-cells this guide helped